# Scala Saddle Filtering Column Values

Tags: scala, saddle

I am new to scala Saddle, I have three column (customer name, age and Status) in a frame. I have to apply filter in column (age). If any customer age having more than 18 I need to set the Status is "eligible" other wise I need to put "noteligible".

Code:

```
f.col("age").filterAt(x => x > 18)  //but how to update Status column
```

Comment: To test for eligibility to vote/drink/smoke that should probably be x >= 18

Comment: richj.,thanks for your reply. I need to change the column values base on age column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frames are immutable containers, so it is probably better to build your frame with the values fully initialised than start with a partially initialised Frame.

```
import org.saddle._

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val names: Vec[Any] = Vec("andy", "bruce", "cheryl", "dino", "edgar", "frank", "gollum", "harvey")
    val ages:  Vec[Any] = Vec(4, 89, 7, 21, 14, 18, 23004, 65)

    def status(age: Any): Any = if (age.asInstanceOf[Int] >= 18) "eligible" else "noteligible"

    def mapper(indexAge: (Int, Any)): (Int, _) = indexAge match {
      case (index, age) => (index, status(age))
      }

    val nameAge:  Frame[Int, String, Any] = Frame("name" -> names, "age" -> ages)
    val ageCol:   Series[Int, Any]        = nameAge.colAt(1)
    val eligible: Series[Int, Any]        = ageCol.map( mapper )

    println("" + nameAge)
    println("" + eligible)

    val nameAgeStatus: Frame[Int, String, _] = nameAge.joinSPreserveColIx(eligible, how=index.LeftJoin, "status")

    println("" + nameAgeStatus)
  }
}
```

If you really need to start from a partially initialised Frame, you can always drop the uninitialised column and add it back with the correctly calculated values.

Although I would prefer to strongly type the data columns, I think a Frame only contains data of one type, and the common type for "Int" and "String" is "Any". This also affects the type signatures of the methods, although you might want to inline them without the type information anyway.

I found that looking at the [scaladoc](https://saddle.github.io/saddle/saddle-core/target/scala-2.9.3/api/org/saddle/Frame.html) helped a lot.

This is the output from the final println call:

```
[8 x 3]
       name   age      status 
     ------ ----- ----------- 
0 ->   andy     4 noteligible 
1 ->  bruce    89    eligible 
2 -> cheryl     7 noteligible 
3 ->   dino    21    eligible 
4 ->  edgar    14 noteligible 
5 ->  frank    18    eligible 
6 -> gollum 23004    eligible 
7 -> harvey    65    eligible
```